# Error #3115: SQL Error

Tags: javascript, air

I keep getting this error when I try to commit a group of executed statements. Details are blank and the message just doesn't give enough information ('SQL Error' only). Anyone run into this error, or have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that on a couple queries before I began the transaction that had the limit param passed on [execute()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/jslr/flash/data/SQLStatement.html#execute()) statement. Which means that those statements were still executing, and had to be [canceled](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/jslr/flash/data/SQLStatement.html#cancel()) before you can commit a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

That error is usually returned when you have no tables defined. Could that be the cause?

Comment: I don't think so, I ran a few queries before I began the transaction on the same table, and no problems.